# C++ incomplete type despite of full definition available

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to instantiate a C++ template which itself uses another template but the error says that the field is incomplete:

```
template <typename T> class T1 { };

template <typename T> class T2
{
    public:
        T2<T> t1;
};

class T_int
{
    public:
        T1<int> t1; //works
        T2<int> t2; //error
};
```

Both templates are fully defined at this point so why is it not possible to use T2 in this case?

EDIT:
I'm aware that classes can't contain themselves. I was just completely blind for this typo.

```
template <typename T> class T2
{
    public:
        T2<T> t1;
};
```

should have been

```
template <typename T> class T2
{
    public:
        T1<T> t1;
};
```

Comment: The error is from `T2<T> t1;` in `T2`.  Not `T2<int> t2;` in `T_int`.  It should be pretty obvious why the first is an error.

Comment: The template attempts to create a class that contains itself. C++ does not allow that. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: `T2<T> t1;` *in* `T2` is a recursive definition. That obviously won't fly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing things out, I was just blind for this typo. `T2<T> t1` was meant to be `T1<T> t1`.